# Two paths for the same method

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-php

Been trying to use Swagger to generate my documentation for my PHP Rest API, using swagger-php.

It's working pretty great, not quite sure if I'm a fan of having huge comment blocks due to the documentation, but that's not the issue.

I have two paths:

```
/user/ [POST]
/user/login [POST]
```

Both of them call the same method in my PHP code: login().

Is there a way for me to say that /user/ [POST] is just an alias of /user/login [POST] ?

I'd like both of them to be present in the list of Operations, complete with their documentation and saying that they do the same thing, just with a different path to provide options to the user.

I could of course copy-paste the comment block, but I really don't want a 50 lines comment block for a one line method that just calls another method.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using references is already possible in swagger-php by using the `@SWG\Path`.

```
/**
 * @SWG\Post(
 *   path="/user/login",
 *   @SWG\Response(response=200, description="OK")
 * )
 * @SWG\Path(path="/user/", ref="#/paths/user~1login");
 */
function login() {
  ...
}
```

But remember that swagger is to **document** your API, if /user/login is the canonical API endpoint for logging in I wouldn't even expose the alias in the swagger docs.

@Mark In swagger-php the *path* still owns the *operations*, but it uses [some tricks](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/src/Processors/BuildPaths.php) to create the `@SWG\Path` automatically, this avoids boilerplate as the general use case is to document one http-method per php method, but if your method handles multiple http-methods it might be shorter to use `@SWG\Path` directly:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Path(
 *   path="/example",
 *   @SWG\Get(response=200, description="OK"),
 *   @SWG\Post(response=200, description="OK"),
 *   @SWG\Put(response=200, description="OK")
 * )
 */
 function thisMethodHandlesGetPostAndPutRequests() {
 }
```

Comment: Even though i don't use swagger-php anymore, I took the time to test this, seems to be working as expected. Marking this as resolved.

Comment: I think it should be `ref="#/paths/~1user~1login"` - the character `/` in `/user/login` needs to be [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164413/113116) as `~1` when used in references.

Comment: The `ref` field is an unexpected field for @SWG\Path annotation for the current version of swagger-php 2.0.12. In addition the encoding of / by ~1 is not implemented in swagger-php

Comment: @Arno I've updated the ref in the example and released in swagger-php 2.0.13, which adds the ref field to @SWG\Path and implements the ~1 encoding.

Comment: @Bob Fanger Thx for the dev, I will check your improvement as soon as possible

Comment: @Helen your `~1` escaping suggestion is incredibly useful, thank you! (anyone can try it and realize it really works on https://editor.swagger.io/)

Comment: no longer possible using swagger-php 4

Answer (score 0):

Using `Swagger 2.0` you can reference a path and avoid duplicating the documentation.

***Example:***

```
{
  "swagger": 2.0,
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Pet"
  },
  "host": "localhost:1234",
  "schemes": [ "http" ],
  "paths": {
    "/pet": { "$ref": "#/paths/x-endpoint-pet" },
    "x-endpoint-pet" : {
        "post": { 
            "tags" : [ "pet" ] 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

[swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) as of version `2.0.6` doesn't support such references however.

This is at least partially due to the specific implementation approach taken in `swagger-php`. The php implementation reverses the ***own-owned*** relation between the ***path*** and the ***operation*** objects.

In the `Swagger 2.0` spec the ***path*** owns the ***operation***, and a ***path*** can reference other ***paths***.

In the `swagger-php` implementation however the ***operation*** owns the ***path***. This then gives the wrong impression that an ***operation*** can have aliases and/or own multiple ***paths***.

This is a conceptual issue which will likely be addressed in a future version of `swagger-php`.

Comment: Your example is correct. May you mention that the `x-endpoint-pet` path does not contain a slash ? If the path contains a slash, you have to encode the slash by `~1`