# Swagger php two path having same method without repetitive doctrine annotation

Tags: php, swagger

[From another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503533/two-paths-for-the-same-method):

```
/**
 * @SWG\Post(
 *   path="/user/login",
 *   @SWG\Response(response=200, description="OK")
 * )
 * @SWG\Path(path="/user/", ref="#/user/login");
 */
function login() {
  ...
}
```

The above code not working - no definition coming in swagger integrated page. Do I need two definitions for same method for different URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the reference to

```
@SWG\Path(path="/user/", ref="#/paths/~1user~1login");
```

OpenAPI/Swagger path references use the syntax `#/paths/path_name`, where *path_name* is the string `/user/login` with the special character `/` escaped as `~1`. ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164413/113116) has more escaping examples.)

Comment: Thanks Helen I'll try.